# Two files from different sources in same Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How do I setup a Spring Batch job that can produce two files from two different sources that should be produced "in parallell"? It doesn't have to be in parallell really, but at least I don't want them to depend on each other. The requirement is that one job should be able to produce two files, with the same timestamp (HHMMss), the content is CSV and they are logically related. For now they run in two steps, step 1 creates file A and step 2 creates file B.

But is there a more correct way of doing this? Or am I approaching this issue wrong?

Comment: did you try http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start 2 different jobs, each in its own thread?

Comment: That forces to process twice the input

Comment: You should probably try to edit your question to make your usecase more clear, and add more information about what you're trying to do.